# Why is a single line comment causing PHP syntax error?

Tags: php

The following code:

```
$a = '?>';
```

is fine but the commented version of the same code:

```
//$a = '?>';
```

causes a syntax error but

```
 /*$a = '?>';*/
```

is fine.

It doesn't make much sense to me how `//$a = '?>';` is translated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php):

> The "one-line" comment styles only comment to the end of the line **or the current block of PHP code**, whichever comes first.

(my emphasis)

The comment comprises the block of characters

```
//$a = '
```

But the `?>` terminates the comment, which means you have a line of PHP reading just

```
';
```

which is invalid PHP

Comment: Might be valuable to add that the comment is the reason '?>' is no longer seen as a string either, which is why the first line is fine.

Comment: I've found explanation here, but it is a bit crazy - http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php#92643

Comment: It is wrong that `';` will be seen as invalid PHP code, because it will appear in HTML-space (and therefore will be output as-is). But it may wreck up the following code. Or, if you use something like `//$a = '?>x<?php';`, your answer is correct. See also https://eval.in/508806